# Fastest way to convert ubyte [0, 255] array to float array [-0.5, +0.5] with NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, normalization, vectorization

The question is in the title and it is pretty straightforward.

I have a file `f` from which I am reading a `ubyte` array:

```
arr = numpy.fromfile(f, '>u1', size * rows * cols).reshape((size, rows, cols))
max_value = 0xFF  # max value of ubyte
```

Currently I'm renormalizing the data in 3 passes, as follows:

```
arr = images.astype(float)
arr -= max_value / 2.0
arr /= max_value
```

Since the array is somewhat large, this takes a noticeable fraction of a second.
It would be great if I could do this in 1 or 2 passes through the data, as I think that would be faster.

Is there some way for me to perform a "composite" vector operation to decrease the number of passes?
Or, is there some other way for me to speed this up?

Comment: Why not `arr = (images.astype(float) / max_value) - 0.5`

Comment: @RicardoCárdenes: Why would you expect that to be faster?

Comment: Not expecting it to be faster right away, just wondering. Anyway, for this I would maybe have a look into some extra module like [numexpr](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr)

Comment: @RicardoCárdenes: Oh I see. Well I'm not doing that because I don't see any benefit to allocating an additional block of memory for no reason instead of doing it in-place, it just evicts data from the CPU cache. That link seems interesting, thanks.

Comment: @Alex: I read it with exactly the code I showed you, using `numpy.fromfile`. Yes, every line takes a few hundred milliseconds, with the division by `max_value` being the slowest operation.

Comment: @Mehrdad This is not entirely correlated but I've seen that python even fails to inline functions. so I would expect vectorisation is far off in the optimizations list. I'm not very familiar with numpy. but you haven't shown any loops in the code. how is that done?

Comment: @Alex: I don't understand what you're asking. "How" is *what* done? The code I gave you is literally the code I have. There are no loops; the entire thing is vectorized as you see -- I'm not hiding anything from you...

Comment: @Mehrdad You could check and make sure that your numpy installation supports SIMD. I don't think is default in distro packages. It should be a nice boost too.

Comment: I think people are confused because, at fist glance, it's not immediately clear that there *are* 'passes'. It looks like you've just showed us the per-element behavior. Only once you've realized that `arr` is the array and performing an operation on it applies that operation to every element is it clear there are passes .

Comment: @Alex I'm interested in how you'd expect in lining to be performed safely at all in a language where any function name could be rebound at run time to any other function/value.  That's part of the same reason that TCO can't be trivially applied in python either.

Comment: Could you be more precise than "somewhat large"?  Megabytes?  Gigabytes?

Comment: @aruisdante actually java can do that (also V8). look at graal/truffle in the javaone conference videos. In truth without proper deoptimization support can't to optimistic (speculative) optimizations. you still could inline to the code having a small type guards. when the type guard fails you fall back to  interpret the bytecode. In truth V8 relies on a sane programmer in an insane type system.

Comment: @Alex True, but you'd also lose proper stack traces (without a lot of scaffolding to preserve them, somewhat defeating the purpose of inlineing), and Python is loathe to lose proper stack traces. Also CPython doesn't do any JIT, and I assume Java/V8 is leveraging JIT to really get a speed boost.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser: No, because the size is irrelevant and I don't want to divert the discussion. The point is that it's large enough to be slow and I want to improve it (and I suspect decreasing the number of passes might help), so I'm wondering if there's any way to do that.

Comment: Sorry, I should have also stated *why* I asked what "somewhat large" means:  I was interested in how the size of the array compares to the size of the L3 cache on the CPU where this will run.  That is definitely not irrelevant.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser: Sigh, it's around 50 MiB. Now what difference did that make?

Comment: Well, *maybe* none!  But given how CPUs are organized these days, size does matter.  In this case, working in batches that fit in L3 cache might improve performance.  How *much* benefit will depend partially on how much Python overhead there is in handling the batches.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser: The batch thing would work if I had more passes but with 3 passes I don't think it will improve anything, at least over what I posted in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a better solution myself (around 25% faster):

```
arr = numpy.memmap(f, '>u1', 'r', shape=(size, rows, cols))
arr = arr / float(max_value)
arr -= 0.5
```

I'm curious if it can be improved.

Comment: For a fair comparison, be sure you clear your file system cache when you time this, otherwise the second time you run it will be a lot faster than the first.

Answer (score 5):

I did:

```
ar = ar - 255/2.
ar *= 1./255
```

Seems faster `:)`

No I timed it, it's roughly twice as fast on my system. It seems `ar = ar - 255/2.` does subtraction and type conversion on the fly. Also, it seems division with a scalar is not optimized: it's faster to do the division once and then a bunch of multiplications on the array. Though the additional floating point operation may increase round-off error.

As noted in the comments, [numexpr](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr) might be a truly fast yet simple way to achieve this. On my system it's another factor two quicker, but mostly due to `numexpr` using multiple cores and not so much the fact it does only a single pass over the array. Code:

```
import numexpr
ar = numexpr.evaluate('(ar - 255.0/2.0) / 255.0')
```

Comment: +1, though I have to note it's not equivalent. `assert 244.0 * (1.0 / 255.0) == 244.0 / 255.0`

Comment: +1 for numexpr. If you don't mind the dependency, it was invented for exactly this type of situation, and it will be impossible to beat in terms of performance I wager.

Answer (score 2):

This lookup table *might* be a bit faster than the repeated calculation:

```
table = numpy.linspace(-0.5, 0.5, 256)
images = numpy.memmap(f, '>u1', 'r', shape=(size, rows, cols))
arr = table[images]
```

On my system, it shaves 10 to 15 percent off the time compared to yours.

Comment: On my system it's twice as slow as my memmap solution.

Answer (score 0):

I get like 50% speed up for large arrays using [`cython.parallel.prange`](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/parallelism.html#cython.parallel.prange) with below code (done for one-dimensional array, but easily extensible); I guess the speed-up depends on the number of CPU cores:

`pilot.pyx` file:

```
cimport cython
from cython.parallel import prange
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
from numpy cimport float64_t, uint8_t, ndarray

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def norm(np.ndarray[uint8_t, ndim=1] img):
    cdef:
        Py_ssize_t i, n = len(img)
        np.ndarray[float64_t, ndim=1] arr = np.empty(n, dtype='float64')
        float64_t * left = <float64_t *> arr.data
        uint8_t * right = <uint8_t *> img.data

    for i in prange(n, nogil=True):
        left[i] = (right[i] - 127.5) / 255.0

    return arr
```

`setup.py` file to build a C extension module out of above code:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

ext_module = Extension(
    'pilot',
    ['pilot.pyx'],
    extra_compile_args=['-fopenmp'],
    extra_link_args=['-fopenmp'],
)

setup(
    name = 'pilot',
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
    ext_modules = [ext_module],
)
```